# Allow traffic from VPN Server clients to server restricted to VPN traffic on Tomato

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, tomato

I currently have Tomato running on my ASUS-Dark-Knight router.  I also have the VPN server feature running which allows me to connect via OpenVPN to the router.

On the flip side, the VPN client feature is connected to a third party VPN provider and using the Routing Policy feature I redirect all traffic from one machine (192.168.10.228) through this VPN.

Using the Admin -> Scripts section I have an IPtables command configured thus:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -s 192.168.10.228 -o `nvram get wan_iface` -j DROP
```

to drop all traffic to and from the server if the VPN fails.  This all works fine.

I am unsure how to configure the router to allow traffic between any VPN client connecting to the router (which is assigned a 10.0.x.0 address) and the server at 192.168.10.228.  I'm assuming i need to add another rule but i'm not sure how to redirect from the VPN Client -> LAN -> Server and back again?

UPDATE: Attached a drawing as request using my rather limited diagraming skills!  I will attempt to put the rules on shortly.

[Link to diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bimjb.png)

Comment: [Linux: routing traffic between two networks with iptables](http://serverfault.com/questions/267580/linux-routing-traffic-between-two-networks-with-iptables) - essentially setup a rule which matches the subnet so `10.0.0.0/16` and `192.168.10.288/32` (or less). You only need this if you do have filtering setup (which is likely).

Comment: So would this be correct (br0 appears to be my bridge according to tomato - I assume I want to use eth0, unsure whether tun0 is my vpn server)

`iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.10.228/24 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -s 192.168.10.228/24 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Yes, it would be what I would try and you need to make sure the forwarding flag is set (though I would wonder if it wasn't).

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting this to work.  I am connected as a client to my VPN at 10.8.0.5 on tun11.  The server I am trying to get to is at 192.168.10.228 but has it's traffic directed up the VPN (tun21).  I can get to it when i'm physically sitting at a machine on the LAN (e.g. 192.168.10.x address) but no matter what rule I add, I cannot get my 10.8.0.x clients to see it?

Comment: Draw up a diagram using something like [Draw.IO](https://www.draw.io/) that includes your structure and interfaces with the assigned addresses. Afterwards write down what rules you setup where in order to forward/redirect traffic. If you have all that information compiled, it's up to you to decide whenever you want to include it as an edit in this question or if the scenario changed enough in order to make it its own question.